# C++ Reading text file into struct data members

Tags: c++, string, struct, fstream

I'm currently trying to load a text file into struct data members. Each number is separated by a comma.

```
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

struct server{
    bool isBusy;
};

struct pass{
    double arrivalTime = 0;
    double serviceTime = 0;
    int classType = 0;
};

int main(){

    string fileName;
    string line;
    pass Pass;

    cout << "Enter file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream fin(fileName);

    while (getline(fin, line, ','))
    {
        /*NEED HELP HERE*/
        fin >> Pass[0].arrivalTime;
        fin >> Pass[0].serviceTime;
        fin >> Pass[0].classType;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the text file.

```
0.951412936,2.131445423,0
1.902743503,2.010703852,0
2.537819984,2.326199911,0
3.425838997,1.603712153,0
3.502553324,0.998192867,0
3.917348666,1.49223429,0
4.391605986,0.831661367,0
4.947059678,0.8557003,0
5.429305232,2.42029408,0
```

The data in the text file follows this format:

arrivalTime,serviceTime,classType

As you can see i have split the line up and stored it in "line" using the comma delimiter, but i am unsure how to load each number into the struct in the while loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a `std::istringstream` initialized with `line`  and read the numbers from that one.

Answer (score 2):

Define an istream `operator >>` for your struct. Something like

```
struct pass {
    double arrivalTime = 0;
    double serviceTime = 0;
    int    classType   = 0;

    friend std::istream & operator >>(std::istream & in, pass & p) {
        char c;
        in >> p.arrivalTime >> c >> p.serviceTime >> c >> p.classType;
        return in;
    }
};
```

Then, simply

```
pass Pass;
fin >> Pass;
```

Comment: This will work as long as the file contains valid data. It would be safer to verify that `c` reads a comma between each field.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I assumed it from OP's example input file.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (getline(fin, line))
{
    sscanf(line.c_str(), "%lf,%lf,%d", &arrivalTime, &serviceTime, &classType);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct server{
    bool isBusy;
};

struct pass{
    double arrivalTime;
    double serviceTime;
    int classType;
    friend std::istream & operator >>(std::istream &in, pass &p) {
        char c;
        in >> p.arrivalTime >> c >> p.serviceTime >> c >> p.classType;
        return in;
    }
};

int main(){

    string fileName;
    string line;
    cout << "Enter file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream fin(fileName.c_str(), ifstream::in);
    vector<pass> passes;
    pass Pass;

    while (fin>>Pass)
      passes.push_back(Pass);

    for(vector<pass>::const_iterator iter = passes.begin(); 
    iter != passes.end();
    ++iter)
      std::cout<<iter->arrivalTime<<" "<<iter->serviceTime<<" "
      <<iter->classType<<std::endl;
```

}

Comment: This will skip lines in the input, because you read a line into `line` then read the next line with `fin >> Pass`, then read a line into `line`, then read the next line with `fin >> Pass` etc.

Comment: @JonathanWakely  You are right: my code was wrong even if its behavior was not exactly what you describe in your comment. However, I edited my answer with right code.

Answer (score 1):

This loop is wrong:

```
while (getline(fin, line, ','))
{
    /*NEED HELP HERE*/
    fin >> Pass[0].arrivalTime;
    fin >> Pass[0].serviceTime;
    fin >> Pass[0].classType;
}
```

You are reading everything from the stream up to the next `','` character, then trying to read more from the stream.

Given the input file:

```
0.951412936,2.131445423,0
1.902743503,2.010703852,0
2.537819984,2.326199911,0
```

Your program reads `"0.951412936"` into `line` (and discards the `','`) then tries to read the next input into `Pass[0].arrivalTime` but the next input is 2.131445423, which was meant to be the serviceTime (which you already read into `line`).

As Shreevardhan [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32499193/981959) you can define an operator for reading your struct from a stream. I would make it more reliable like so:

```
struct ExpectedChar { char expected; };

// read a character from a stream and check it has the expected value
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, const ExpectedChar& e)
{
  char c;
  if (in >> c)
    if (c != e.expected)  // failed to read expected character
      in.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
  return in;
}

// read a struct pass from a stream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, pass& p)
{
  ExpectedChar comma{ ',' };
  in >> p.arrivalTime >> comma >> p.serviceTime >> comma >> p.classType;
  return in;
}
```

This will stop reading if the input file does not meet the expected format. Now you can do:

```
while (fin >> Pass)
{
  // do something with each pass
}
if (!fin.eof())  // stopped reading before end-of-file
  throw std::runtime_error("Invalid data in input file");
```

This will keep reading a `pass` from the file until reading fails, either because it reached the end of the file, or because there was some bad data in the file. If there is bad data it throws an exception.

Comment: When adding both operator definitions and "struct ExpectedChar { char expected; };" into the definition of struct pass as @Shreevardhan provided, an error saying "too many parameters for this operator function" occurred. I want to use your method, can you please give me a little help? Thank you!

Comment: @Lucifer don't add them to the definition of `struct pass`, they are not supposed to be members of that struct. If you do add them inside that struct, you need to declare the operators with `friend`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is hint;

```
string line;
string temp;            
string::size_type sz;
while (getline(cin, line))   
{
    istringstream ss( line );
    getline( ss, temp, ',' );  
    double arrivalTime = stod(temp, &sz);
    getline( ss, temp, ',' );  
    double serviceTime = stod(temp, &sz);
    getline( ss, temp, ',' );  
    double classType = stod(temp, &sz);

    cout << arrivalTime << ' ' 
         << serviceTime << ' ' 
         << classType   << endl;
}
```